# want something (to be) adjective

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice

I always thought the verb "want " requires "to", whether it's a verb or an adjective. But I heard a lot of people just saying the adjective without " to be."
I wonder whether this is grammatical or it's just dropped in casual settings.

ex)

I want (would like) the beef to be medium.
I want (would like) the beef medium.

Comment: When Al Capone gets *really* upset with someone, he shouts [***I want him dead!***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHs3XuTqQSg) If it suits you to imagine a "deleted" ***to be*** there, you can. But native speakers wouldn't really think of it like that, any more than they would think of *I want him off my back!* as "short for" *I want him **to be** off my back* (which is syntactically valid, but *very* unlikely from a native speaker).

Answer (score 4):

"I want the beef medium" is used informally since the words "to be" can be dropped without changing the meaning. This is because the *"to be"* is implied.

Edit: See [@FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers)' comment about this, it explains it well.