# 'destroyed' or 'to be destroyed'

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

> I want the balls destroyed.

> I want the balls to be destroyed.

If not which one is preferred?

Comment: You need to remove the comma in the first sentence, then both will be correct, and both will mean the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When exactly can "to be" be omitted in the sentence? (want ~ to be p.p)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217628/when-exactly-can-to-be-be-omitted-in-the-sentence-want-to-be-p-p) Also [want something (to be) adjective](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139849/want-something-to-be-adjective) and [Complex Object with words that express desire/intention and infinitive Verb in passive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295195/complex-object-with-words-that-express-desire-intention-and-infinitive-verb-in-p) and probably others.

Answer (score -1):

In first sentence, remove  the comma, unless you mean that you want someone to bring you the balls in a broken state.

The second insists on the necessity to do it in a near future, usually by someone else (a subordinate, for example).

Comment: I don't think whether or not ***to be*** is included has anything to do with how ***soon*** the speaker wants something done. The format doesn't work so well with all "past participle adjectives" though. ***I want him dead*** sounds like a natural enough thing for a gangster to say, but ***I want him to be dead*** sounds a bit weird to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "I want him to be dead" sounds weird because "dead" is a state and not an action like killed or buried. To emphasize urgency, *to be* or not *to be* ?